# Access photos on USB iPhone 8 plus through node js

Tags: node.js, iphone, usb

Seems simple enough. I'm trying to access the photos on an iPhone 8 plus through node js. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Upload to server running on node is one way to do it. But generally accessing the filesystem of IOS devices in not straight forward.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that that would be easier, but that's not what I need. I'm looking for some way to access the filesystem of an IOS device connected via USB. I've been looking and looking and can't seem to find the knowledge or a library that could help me with this.